# Aggregate two tasks printing sections and storing specific strings

Tags: bash

I would like to aggregate the following two tasks together.

The first selects sections for printing using the section structure, where `KEYWORDS` consist of keywords separated by commas (e.g. bash,recource).

```
## NFAML [NASMB] KEYWORDS
## BODY (can include empty lines)
## END OF NFAML [NASMB]
```

I want to print the sections whilst also capture the three different parts `NFAML`, `NASMB`, `KEYWORDS`.  For `KEYWORDS`, I want to split them by comma and store all the keywords in an array.

```
spc='[[:space:]]*'
ebl='\\['  # awk needs it for applying \[
ebr='\\]'  # awk needs it for applying \]
pn_ere='^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+'

nfaml=${faml:-"[[:graph:]]+"}  # Use GPH if FAML null ("" or '')
nasmb=${asmb:-"[[:graph:]]+"}  # Use GPH if ASMB null ("" or '')

cmt='\/\/' ; ebl='\[' ; ebr='\]'  # for sed to apply // ] [
spc='[[:space:]]*' ; gph="[[:graph:]]+"

local kys=".*"
local pn_ere="^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|${cmt})[[:space:]]+"
beg_ere="${pn_ere}(${nfaml}) ${ebl}(${nasmb})${ebr}${spc}(${kys})$"
end_ere="${pn_ere}END OF ${nfaml} ${ebl}${nasmb}${ebr}${spc}$"

while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $beg_ere ]]; then
    title=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    subtitle=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    keywords=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    echo "Title: $title"
    echo "Subtitle: $subtitle"
    echo "Keywords: $keywords"
  fi
done < $filename

awk -v pnre="$pn_ere" -v begrsc="$beg_ere" -v endrsc="$end_ere" \
    '$0 ~ beg_ere { insc=1; next }
     $0 ~ end_ere { insc=0; print "" }
     insc { sub(pn_ere,""); print }' "$filename"
```

Have started on the following idea

```
awk -v beg_ere="$beg_ere" -v pn_ere="$pn_ere" -v end_ere="$end_ere" '
  $0 ~ beg_ere { 
    title=gensub(beg_ere, "\\1", "g", $0);
    subtitle=gensub(beg_ere, "\\2", "g", $0);
    keywords=gensub(beg_ere, "\\3", "g", $0);
    split(keywords, kaggr, ",");
    print "Title: " title;
    print "Subtitle: " subtitle;
    print "Keywords: " keywords;
    print "kaggr: " kaggr;
    next
  }
  $0 ~ pn_ere { 
    $0=gensub(pn_ere, "", "g", $0);
    print $0
  }
  $0 ~ end_ere { 
    print ""
  }
' "$filename"
```

Comment: What are your thoughts so far on how you think you can do it, and where do you struggle?

Comment: Do all of the start lines have `SOMENAME [OTHERNAME] KEYWORDS` and all end lines have `END OF SOMENAME [OTHERNAME]`? What separates the end of one block and the start of the next? Blank lines allowed? Any other intervening text?

Comment: Yes, start and end lines are as you say.  There can be any intervening text, including blank lines.

Comment: Can the intervening lines contain a field 2 with `[ ... ]`? If not, why not just identify the start by conditioning the start-rule with `$2 ~ /[[].+[]]/ { your rule }` and within it loop `i = $3; i <= $NF; i++` to separate keywords into an array and save `name = $1` and `other = $2`. Then for the ending rule simply do `$1 == "END" && $2 == "OF" && name == $3 && other = $4 { your ending rule }`. That will simplify things quite a bit. (or course that is outline and there are other checks to include)

Comment: My initial thought of this is not to allow intervening lines subscribing to `beg_ere`.

Comment: I could do `split(keywords, keyword_array, /, */)`.  I would need some idea how the new code for all this would look like though.

Comment: How can I declare the array in `awk`.  Should the declaration be made in a `BEGIN` instance?

Comment: You don't have to "declare" an array. You can simply start using one, e.g. `arr[foo] = x` will assign the value `'x'` to the associative array `arr` at the index `foo` (all arrays are associative in awk, but you can use indexes to make them act like indexed arrays, e.g. `arr[++n] = x` assigns `'x'` to the `1` index of `arr`. (and so on). The only time you need `BEGIN` is if you want to *Initialize* array indexes and values. That can be done in `BEGIN`, so the array is already built before you start processing rules.

Comment: There is no need to initialise tho array.  If the understanding is settled, then an answer to the question is all that remains.